# How can I get my array to work when assigning non-sequential numeric indexes in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, xml, arrays, autocomplete

I have an XML file dynamically created from a database where each item has both an id and name. In the following syntax:

```
<item>
   <id>1</id>
   <name>FirstName</name>
</item>
```

... and so on ...

I am trying to use these values for a jQuery autocomplete, where the ID will be submitted via form when the name is selected from the autocomplete.

I've tried the following block of code (executed from a button within a form):

```
function listItems(){
    var dataString = "";
    dataString += $("form#getItemsForm").serialize(); 

    $.ajax({ type: 'GET', url: 'myXML.xml', dataType: 'xml', success: function(xml){
        var myList = new Array();
        $('restaurant', xml).each(function() {
            var myId = Number($(this).find('id').text());
            var myName = $(this).find('name').text();
            myList[myId] = myName;  
        });
        alert(myList);
        $('.listItems').autocomplete({source:myList});
    }});
}
```

However, this is not working as the IDs begin at 1 and the array is searching for an index of zero so when I alert myList it popups with ,FirstName,SecondName (instead of FirstName,SecondName -- no leading comma).

I've tried making an array of objects but that's a little more cryptic to me as my alert returns [object Object] for each item.

Any pointers would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the name attribute to appear as the 'label' of the item and the id to be the 'value', you could do this:

```
var myList = [];
$('restaurant', xml).each(function() {
    var myId = Number($(this).find('id').text());
    var myName = $(this).find('name').text();
    myList.push({label: myName, value: myId});  
});
```

Relevant excerpt from the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-source):

> The local data can be a simple Array
>   of Strings, or it contains Objects for
>   each item in the array, with either a
>   label or value property or both. The
>   label property is displayed in the
>   suggestion menu. The value will be
>   inserted into the input element after
>   the user selected something from the
>   menu. If just one property is
>   specified, it will be used for both,
>   eg. if you provide only
>   value-properties, the value will also
>   be used as the label.

Comment: Hmmm, quoting seems to be broken in Chrome. Can anyone else confirm this?

Comment: Excellent. This is certainly a starting point to where I need to go. Thank you!